# Surrey woodland - what is this plant?

Tags: identification, trees, woodland

Found amongst bluebells. The local vegetation is made up of heath, chestnut trees and English oaks. I didn’t see any other similar plants around it. Any idea what it could be?[image: unknown plant 1][image: close up]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question: it would appear to be a **common lime tree** (*tilia x europaea*).

1. The first clue was in one of the pictures: the stomp of a big tree can be seen in the background. It looked likely this was an offshoot of that tree.
2. Searching for sweet chestnut tree leaf pictures (my first guess) landed me on a page which has a handy guide to trees commonly found in Britain. The leaves match the Tilia Europaea. Source: [countrylife.co.uk](https://www.countrylife.co.uk/gardens/a-simple-guide-to-identifying-british-trees-85493)